# unable to connect with database using symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have created a simple registration form which takes some data. I have prepared the code on another system. when I am installing on my system. I have created the bundle and registered into `AppKernel.php`. 
I have created the database using `php app/console doctrine:databse:create`. database has been generated successfully. 
and then I have imported my `sql` file there and updated schema using the command line.

but now when I am running the code then I am able to see the registration page but when i am clicking on submit button then i am getting an error.

```
Error in signing up, Please try again
```

what may be the possible reasons?

```
public function registerAction(){

    $logger = $this->get('logger');
    $request = $this->get('request');
    $user_id = $request->cookies->get('formbuilder_login');

    if (is_null($user_id)){
        return $this->render('FormBuilderFBBundle:Login:register.html.twig', array('page_title' => 'SignUp'));
    }

    return $this->render('FormBuilderFBBundle:Login:loggedin.html.twig', array('page_title' => 'LoggedIn'));

}
```

Comment: We do need to know about you registration logic of course - put the relevant bits here.

Comment: `public function registerAction(){ 
 $logger = $this->get('logger');
 $request = $this->get('request');
 $user_id = $request->cookies->get('formbuilder_login');
 if (is_null($user_id)){
     return $this->render('FormBuilderFBBundle:Login:register.html.twig', array('page_title' => 'SignUp'));
 }
 return $this->render('FormBuilderFBBundle:Login:loggedin.html.twig', array('page_title' => 'LoggedIn'));
    }`

Comment: This page is just the registration form, not the actual register action - search for such action in your code and edit your question so we can have a look ^^